# Powershell, win server domain profiles deletion with special symbols

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm really bad at scripting but in any case I need to create a script which should delete special domain accounts with special naming convention. We are using power shell v3. I'm stuck at the filtering profiles area. I have a lot of profiles with bird numbers like: bb1231X, ba1231z, bb1231rw. So I want to delete only the profiles which contain BB****X for example and to double check mark it as 7 symbols and 7 symbol should be X and beginning should be BB.

And do not know how to write this double check. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Current script:

```
Function Get-System-Drive-Clean {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$computerName
    )

    PROCESS {

        foreach ($computer in $computerName) {
            Write-Verbose "Housekeeping on $computer"
            Write-Verbose "Mapping drive \\$computer\c$"
            $drive = New-PSDrive -Name $computer.replace(".","-") -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\$computer\C$ 
            write-Verbose "Checking windows version"
            #Cheking windows version
            $version = (Get-WmiObject  -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem ).version
            Write-Verbose "Windows version $version"


            #Profile Deleting area.
            if ($version -ge 6) {
                 write-Verbose "Getting profiles from WMI (Win 2k8 and above)..."   
                $profiles = Get-WmiObject Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $computer -Filter "LocalPath like 'C:%R'"


                if ($profiles -ne $null) {
                    $profiles | foreach { 
                        Write-Verbose ("Deleting profile: " + $_.LocalPath)
                        #$_.Delete()
                        #| Where {(!$_.Special) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5))}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) (or `regex` for short) are your friends, and PowerShell has native support for them!

You can use the `-match` operator to do regex matching:

```
PS C:\> 'BB8972X' -match '^BB.{4}X$'
True
PS C:\> 'BA9042W' -match '^BB.{4}X$'
False
```

The pattern I used in the example above (`^BB.{4}X$`) works as follows:

- `^`: The bare caret character means "start of string position"
- `BB`: This is simply two `B` characters
- `.{4}`: In regex, `.` means "any character". `{4}` is a quantifier meaning "exactly 4 of the preceding character", so 4 of any character
- `X`: The letter X
- `$`: This means "end of string position"

So, if you have a number of Directories with these names and only want the ones where the name is like `BB****X`, you'd do:

```
$BBXDirs = Get-ChildItem -Directory |Where-Object {$_.Name -match '^BB.{4}X$'}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks Jessen for replly. Trying to add regex as you showed:
$profiles = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_UserProfile -filter "LocalPath Like 'C:\\Users\\%'" -Match '^b.{5}r$'
but i got an error.
Get-WmiObject : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Match'
.
At line:19 char:125
+ ... C:\\Users\\%'" -Match '^b.{5}r$'
+                    ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-WmiObject], ParameterB
   indingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.GetWmiObjectCommand

Comment: You can't use regex (ie. the `-match` operator) inside a WMI query, it's a *PowerShell* language feature

Comment: yup, it just worked! you are awsome! :)
So basicaly i have now script which deleting profiles, but maybe you know how to delete profile information in the registry, as i believe it can be a problem if the reg file wont be cleaned up from unused sids.